# Beginner PHP. Regular expression, excluding characters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a regex for my form that will accept lower case characters a-z, upper case A - Z and all numbers.

I have successfully included what needs to be accepted, but what I want to do is exclude the following characters  `$£*`

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ^$£* ]{1,20}$/", $webdata['familypa']))
```

Comment: That pattern does not include `$£*`.

Comment: I don't see a problem maybe you don't need that negation `!`?

Comment: Non-accepted characters are rejected... So?

Comment: You need to show `$webdata['familypa']` and what result you get that is not expected.

Comment: Apologies, I had not included the excluded characters from my code. Post now edited,

Comment: Now you updated the code mixing accepted AND rejected characters. Not understanding what you are doing here...

Comment: Please put different input strings and expected results without any further explanation.

Comment: Put it back the way it was and it works fine.  You don't need to **exclude** them because they are NOT **included**.

Comment: @MarkFenwick We cannot help you properly if you don't clarify your coding intent and offer some sample input/output.  Show us a small battery of input strings, then tell us exactly what kind of result you expect from each.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern can be accurately/concisely written as:

`~^[a-z\d]{1,20}$~i`

```
if(!preg_match('~^[a-z\d]{1,20}$~i',$webdata['familypa'])){
    echo 'familypa is not an alpha-numeric string or doesn\'t have a length of between 1 & 20 characters';
}else{
    echo 'familypa is all good';
}
```

Or you can write a more verbose, non-regex method:

*The conditional checks for positive length, then length less than 21, then alpha-numeric.

```
if($len=strlen($webdata['familypa']) && $len<21 && ctype_alnum($webdata['familypa'])){
    echo 'familypa is all good';
}else{
    echo 'familypa is not an alpha-numeric string or doesn\'t have a length of between 1 & 20 characters';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex expression for accepting lower case characters a-z, upper case A - Z and all numbers (considering any number 0-9 ) is the following : `regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/`